# Monitoring non-dynamic method calls when working with child classes inheriting from DynamicObject

Tags: c#, .net, oop, dynamic

Let's say I have a class which inherits from DynamicObject:

```
public class DynamicBase : DynamicObject
{
   public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
    {
      //Yadda yadda yadda
    }

    //same for TrySetMember
}
```

and then I have a child class which inherits from DynamicBase:

```
public class ChildClass : DynamicBase
{
   public void SomeProperty { get; set; }
}
```

I'd like to monitor both the getter and setter of "SomeProperty" in the child class automatically.  Currently, because SomeProperty exists in the child, methods are not routed to TryGet/SetMember or any other override of DynamicObject.

Ideally I would like this behavior after the user of the base class instantiates the object, like so:

```
var someInstance = new ChildClass();
someInstance.SomeProperty = "someValue" //Monitored somehow in DynamicBase
```

as opposed to having to create an instance of DynamicBase, with the child passed as a type (which is how Moq creates interceptors using DynamicProxy):

```
var someInstance = new DynamicBase<ChildClass>();
```

I'm wondering if:

1. This is even possible with C#?
2. If DynamicObject is the wrong base class; should I drop down to IDynamicMetaObjectProvider or something else?
3. If I need to take the route of DynamicBase to create a proxy around ChildClass with the combined behavior I'm looking for, using something like DynamicProxy to intercept calls?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible with the `dynamic` infrastructure added in 4.0. Simply implementing `IDynamicMetaObjectProvider` doesn't mean your class gets to completely overrule .NET's type / member resolution. It just means that when an instance is referenced in the dynamic context, calls that *can't* be resolved otherwise statically will fall back to the dynamic provider.